# How to Store multilingual data in an RDBMS on cloud

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-spanner

I have to create an RDBMS table on Google cloud that supports multilingual data. Do we have a service on google cloud for that? CloudSQL or CloudSpanner?

This is for storing movie titles data from different countries and do some querying on the data.

I expect that I can do queries on the data that is stored. For example: Do a DISTINCT on the movie titles and it should list all different movie titles from various countries (Ex: I have chinese movie titles, Russian movie titles).

Answer (score 1):

In both Google Cloud SQL and Google Cloud Spanner you are able to store multilingual data and do queries with “DISTINCT” or something else. So, you choose the service that will serve your purpose in a better and more effective way.

> Cloud SQL is a fully managed relation database service.
>
> Cloud Spanner is a fully managed, scalable, relational database
>   service for regional and global application data.

You can find more information about the use cases of [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) and [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/) in Google’s documentation.